# Pipelining to find an element at an index

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequence, pipelined-function

I would like to do the following in F#:

```
let index = 5
let sequence = [0..10]
let fifthElement =
    sequence
    |> .[index]
```

However, the last line is invalid. What I'd like to do is to actually retrieve the element at the index of 5 in the `sequence`. Am I doing things wrong?

From what I understand, pipelining helps to reverse the function call, but I am not sure how to retrieve the element at a particular index using pipelining.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `list` and `seq`, I usually use

```
let fifthElement = sequence |> Seq.nth index
```

You could also write

```
let fifthElement = sequence |> fun sq -> sq.[index]
```

or more concisely without piping

```
let fifthElement = sequence.[index]
```

for any object with [Indexed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202).

The advantage of using Indexed Property is that it's actually `O(1)` on array while `Seq.nth` on array is `O(N)`.

Comment: Isn't `Seq.nth` `O(N)` versus `Array.get` being `O(1)`? It might be `O(1)` only if it uses dynamic type tests to specialize for arrays, is that the case?

Comment: @toyvo: In this case, sequence is a list so it's `O(N)`. I would use a specific function for each type rather than do type tests

Answer (score 9):

Just an update:
`nth` is deprecated, you can now use `item` for sequences and lists

example:

```
let lst = [0..2..15] 
let result = lst.item 4
```

result = 8